Should I work with a studio or by myself?
While writing my script, I started thinking about budget and animation quality, and how much time it'll take (and sleep I'll lose :,] ) making this series. It would be nice working with a studio, producing episodes would be quicker, and might be much nicer on my sleep schedule (Maybe.. I hope... probably not, I'll keep dreaming. Or daydreaming, in this case.)
But at the same time working by myself would be great, too. Working on my own time, not having to manage a studio whatsoever, not to mention if I were to work with a studio, the series would most likely be picked up by an existing studio, which increases the chance of popularity, which means possible needy/picky fans that might make production feel rushed.
Popularity is what I'm aiming for, but also not aiming for at the same time. Popularity is nice, for me it could mean a chance to work with or communicate with some of my favorite content creators, but it seems exhausting at the same time, and the main reason for me trying to make this in the first place is for myself, it seems like it could feel freeing, making something I like and finding people who are like me because of it, making something that can help me be honest about who I am and what I enjoy, instead of matching what other people like because it's "normal".
Wouldn't working by myself be too stressful? Wouldn't working with a studio make the series feel more like I'm forced to make it? At the same time, working with myself seems more enjoyable, and would be a great plan b if I decide I can't contact a studio. But if I can hire one, should I?

If you have an idea for a story that you are developing as a script for an animated series, then you don't need a studio.  If a studio hired you, they'd want you to work on developing their story ideas in to scripts so they could animate them and sell them to content publishers --- TV, Netflix, where ever.
If you want to work with a studio to animate your script idea, then what you need is representation or an agent. Their job is to put your work in front of studios that are likely to be interested in buy your scripts. That said, once you sell your script, you lose all control over product. They decide the quality and tone of animation and voice over work. And, that is because they are fronting the $$$ to create the product. They are taking the risks, so they get to make the decisions.
If you want to retain creative control, then you can hire animators and a production team and voice over talent to produce your own series.  Then, you'll need to sell it you someone, and that needs an agent. But probably a different kind of agent that would sell your script.  My understanding is that they are kind of siloed.
